# React app build broken on heroku but works on local

Tags: reactjs, firebase, heroku, webpack

I am developing a React app with webpack locally and have no issues running it on dev-server mode. I also have successfully build the app locally and run it off a local server with no issues. All internal functions were working well.

However upon deployment onto heroku, the build doesn't seem to be able to find the firebase config. This is done via dotenv files to differentiate testing and development variables. I can't seem to find a reason for this as I have tried to print out these variables in both the dev-server mode and local build and they were all printing out correct values.

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "direct-compete",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.4.0"
  },
  "author": "Malik badaruddin",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "parcel watch public/index.html ",
    "parcel:build": "parcel build public/index.html --out-dir dist",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config=jest.config.json",
    "start": "node server/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "firebase": "4.2.0",
    "formik": "^1.3.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "punycode": "^2.1.1",
    "raf": "3.3.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dates": "^18.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-with-direction": "^1.3.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.22.0",
    "yup": "^0.26.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "enzyme": "3.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test '){
    require('dotenv').config({path:'.env.test'});
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    require('dotenv').config({path:'.env.development'});
}
module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === 'production';
    const CSSExtract = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "styles.css"
    });


    return {
        entry: ['@babel/polyfill','./src/app.js'],
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'public','dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]

            }]
        },
        plugins: [
            CSSExtract,
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY' : JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN' : JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL' : JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID' : JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_BUCKET' : JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_BUCKET),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID' :JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID)
            })
        ],
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' :'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            historyApiFallback: true,
            publicPath :'/dist/'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the variables to heroku directly? [Setting heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard)

Comment: Cool thanks...i was having the impression that it would take variables off webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set variables in Heroku, have a look at the official docs on [using-the-heroku-dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard).

1. Go to your project's **Settings**
2. Click on **Reveal Config Vars**

[image]

3. Add your config var **key** and **value** and click **Add**

[image]